# Reversing an array - understanding the solution

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been working through Eloquent JS and couldn't figure out the "reversing an array" problem.

There are parameters to the question such as not being able to use arr.reverse. Anyways, the solution to reversing the same array, in place, threw me off guard and I am looking for someone to help break it down.

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(arr) {
  var length = (Math.floor(arr.length))/2;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var old = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = old;
 }
  return arr;
}
```

I feel like this would be the breakdown:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(arr) {
  var length = (Math.floor(arr.length))/2;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var old = arr[i];                  // var old now equals 1
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i]; //  5 - 1 - 0 = 4. Arr[i] = 4
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = old;   // 4th position of arr = 1
                                    // new arr is 4,2,3,1,5 ?
 }
  return arr; 
}


 var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

The solution works, so obviously my logic is off. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Array indexes start at zero, so `arr[4]` is `5`, not `4`.

Comment: Oh wow I'm dumb. I was getting thrown off because of the .length being 5 and subtracting 1. That makes perfect sense now though. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy pointed out in a comment:

> Array indexes start at zero, so `arr[4]` is `5`, not `4`.